# filtering the list using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, filtering, angularjs-filter

See my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dhaneshmane/7yq9gp62/1/)

I have list of books label with "comic" and "fiction" in my list.

on top I have all label and if you click on each label then books labled with that text should only be displayed.

If I get the JSON key at parent level in JSON then it works perfect.
but in this case I have label key as cid and I need to sort basic on that key.

this is my js code

```
function Test($scope) {
  $scope.persons = [{
               "s": "book1",
              "cl": [{
                  "cn": "fiction",
                  "cid": 1
              }]
          }, {
               "s": "book 2",
              "cl": [{
                  "cn": "comic",
                  "cid": 2
              }]
          }];
}
```

any idea?

Comment: You need to post your code, otherwise this question will be closed soon.

Comment: Post your code here. Questions should be self contained

Comment: All code is in Fiddle

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-click` in each tab and call a function with a value .based on that value you can filter the `array` to new `array`.
  like this

```
  <span ng-click="setTab(1)">fiction</span> | 
  <span ng-click="setTab(2)">comic</span> |
  <span ng-click="setTab(3)">No filter</span>
```

and in controller

```
$scope.setTab = function(a) {
      $scope.s=a;
      //filter your array based on the value
      /*if(a===1){ filter fictions} and so on */
   }
```

see my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nisham/aafvxmbn/79/) for starting

Comment: hey Thanks Nisham but question was about filtering.